# Chronicle queue writes moveToIndex log on each empty read

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

Chronicle queue writes ***moveToIndex*** log on each call on `excerptTailer.readDocument(message)` **after a rollcycle reaches**.
This log comes only when there is no messages available in the queue.
Is it an expected behavior? does it make any problem if the appender got idle  for long time ?

I have a case that the reader stops reading messages and return false even the appender still writes messages to the queue. But I'm unable to find out the scenario. That's why I doubted the log.

Log follows,

```
16:52:19.783 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:20.784 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:21.785 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:22.785 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:23.786 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:24.787 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:25.787 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
16:52:26.788 [Chronicle Reader] DEBUG n.o.c.q.i.s.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer - moveToIndex: 17ec5f2 3
```

My Chronicle-Queue version: **4.5.27**

Comment: I suggest trying the latest snapshot which shouldn't do this.

Comment: Thanks Peter. When can we expect a maven release ?

Comment: supported clients get regular releases, I am discussing with my team this week when the next public release should be.